# Adding a random value only to points of an array that obey certain condition

Tags: python

I have this code that already does what I intend to do, just that goes a bit against optimization as I am using `for` loops and, as I understand, is generally a bad idea.

```
Nx=100
Ny=100
A=np.random.normal(0,scale=2,size=(Nx,Ny))
for x in range(0,Nx):
    for y in range(0,Ny):
        if (A[x,y]*A[x,y] < 1): 
            A[x,y]+=np.random.normal(0)*(1-A[x,y]**2)
```

The thing is I have no idea how I can write in python a code that does the same without the `for` loops.

I have found no answer to this as I have only found questions/answers that focused on summing all the terms of an array that obey a specific statement.
In my case I'm interested in summing a different random number to each of this positions in the array that obey my statement.

Comment: `np.random.normal(0)` has to be different for each iteration, so I am not sure how a vectorised operation would fit in here. You can generate a list of random numbers in advance but then the whole point of randomness during each iteration is gone. If a single random number was required for all iterations, you could have simply done `A[A<1] += np.random.normal(0)*(1-A[A<1]**2)`

Comment: who has told you "for loops are generally a bad idea"?  That's not true.  There are certain classes of loops that can be written more concisely, and possibly even some that can help the compiler, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't write code the way it makes sense for you.

Comment: Donald Knuth, one of the brainiacs of early computing, made a statement that is more true today than when he said it: " premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming" - write code that works, and that you understand, and then move on.  Come back to it if it turns out to be too slow in your experience of using the code.

Comment: @Steve, usually, when using `numpy`, you ill (have to) try to make use of vectorization to keep your code running with C speed. Agreed, most python for-loops are slow not because looping itself is slow, but because the inner block is calling a lot of functions and methods, which is very expensive in Python.

Comment: @Jan, like I said, come back to it if what you've written is too slow for your own situation.  Computers are getting faster and faster.  People spend a lot of time optimizing code so it will run in 10 milliseconds rather than 100.  Either one isn't going to be noticed, so why bother.

Comment: @Steve: I cannot agree more with your 10 millisecond point, especially for non production purposes.

Comment: @Steve Usually the runtime difference between pure `numpy` code and falling back to Python code is several orders of magnitude. Of course it does not matter if your absolute runtime is small to begin with. But the speedup is actually the whole point of using `numpy` in the first place. It makes sense to practice using it properly.

Comment: @Jan - Point taken.  I don't necessarily disagree.  Numpy is a particular domain, and I don't know that domain, so maybe general practices do not apply to it.  My point was to not get bent out of shape over this issue if the code is already fast enough for the intended use.  But if we're talking about learning the proper way to use numpy, I see your point. -

Comment: @Steve I have not tested the answers, but apparently it can be sped up considerably (both are about a factor of 30x faster than the Python code). Whether the `numpy` code is actually vectorized, or just faster because it avoids the overhead of the additional (Python) function calls I cannot say right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.where` from Python like this :

```
import numpy as np
Nx = 100
Ny = 100
A = np.random.normal(0, scale=2,size=(Nx, Ny))
A[np.where((A**2) < 1)] += np.random.normal(0) * (1 - A[np.where((A**2) < 1)]**2)
```

that's the advantage of the array. We can apply arithmetic calculates efficiently and quickly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are fine with generating a list of random numbers to start with, you can vectorise your code as follows

```
Nx = 100
Ny = 100
A = np.random.normal(0, scale=2, size=(Nx, Ny))

# Create conditional mask
mask = A**2 < 1

# generate random numbers
randoms = np.random.normal(0, size=A[mask].shape)

# Modify the values where mask condition is fulfilled.
A[mask] += randoms * (1 - A[mask]**2)
```

**Below is a working example for smaller test case**

```
np.random.seed(10)
Nx = 4
Ny = 4
A = np.random.normal(0, scale=2, size=(Nx, Ny))
print (A)

#[[ 2.66317301  1.43055795 -3.09080058 -0.0167677 ]
# [ 1.24267195 -1.44017112  0.53102317  0.21709705]
# [ 0.00858286 -0.34920042  0.86605238  2.40607475]
# [-1.93013134  2.05654816  0.45726026  0.89027523]]

# Create conditional mask
mask = A**2 < 1

# generate random numbers
randoms = np.random.normal(0, size=A[mask].shape)

# Modify the values where mask condition is fulfilled.
A[mask] += randoms * (1 - A[mask]**2)
print (A)

#[[ 2.66317301  1.43055795 -3.09080058 -1.15305035]
# [ 1.24267195 -1.44017112  0.62805339  1.63166615]
# [-1.07114248 -2.08576267  0.43029076  2.40607475]
# [-1.93013134  2.05654816  0.66769863  1.38494135]]
```

Comment: This answer was very good and pretty time-efficient, 10 times faster or more than my original code. However the solution using `np.where` was even more efficient. Thank you both.